# FindOneAndUpdate a Nested Array in My Mongoose Model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Model Schema that looks like the following

```
sessionSchema = new Schema(
{
    day: { type: Date, required: true },
    training_block: [
        {
            start: { type: String },
            session_notes: { type: String },
            end: { type: String },
        },
       
    ],
    days_notes: { type: String },
    petId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Pet", required: true },

},);
```

In my app I have a API call to find and update a session's training_block with PATCH. My front end request is working fine but I think I am setting up the FindOneAndUpdate mongoose query incorrectly. Even though I thought I was doing it just like examples I found in other threads on the forum. Here is what my query to the database looks like.

```
findOneUpdateDetails: function (req, res, model) {

    console.log(req.params.session) // logged as the expected value 5f1ae779ebb86c229546d5ea
    console.log(req.params.block) // logged as the expected value 5f1b007d43cae7266ff193de
    console.log(req.body) // logged as the expected object { session_notes: 'Now Its Gone' }

    model
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": req.params.session, "training_block._id": req.params.block },
        {
          $set: req.body,
        },
        { new: true }
      )
      .then((dbModel) => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch((err) => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
```

With this I am finding the correct session but its not going to the correct training_block and updating the field I wish to update. Req.Body by the way is a object with the { fieldname: "string value" } so I can use this same query for any field I am trying to update.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I hope I've provided enough information. Lastly if it helps here is the res being sent back to the front end.

```
day: "2020-07-24T13:51:53.066Z"
petId: "5f1a63f65110a71ec6876b82"
training_block: Array(2)
0: {_id: "5f1b007d43cae7266ff193de", start: "05:45", end: "05:59", session_notes: "tThis is some text"}
1: {_id: "5f1ca6466c3fb80dff0b5aca", start: "17:30", end: "17:45", session_notes: "asdffasdfasdfasfd"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__v: 0
_id: "5f1ae779ebb86c229546d5ea"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking and looking I think what I was messing up was passing through into req.body an object constructed like this { session_notes: 'Now Its Gone' } what ended up working was using { training_block.$.session_notes: 'Now Its Gone' }.

Im not totally sure why this works but I think its because training_block is an array and using the .$. iterates through the array to get to the object I want to $set. Maybe someone else can clarify that a little more for me. But my initial problem is solved.